# Insufficient Funds Error

Tags: go-ethereum

I am facing some issue in executing the `eth.sendTransaction` method. Though there is sufficient amount of balance in the transferring account, I am still getting **insufficient funds error**. I've tried passing a hexadecimal number to the `value` field of the `abc` object, but it still doesn't work.

`eth.sendTransaction` works fine when the `from` account is set to `eth.accounts[0]`, for any other account, it throws this error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no enough balance for your balance, cost consists of `value` and transaction fee(gasPrice * gasLimit). So you must deposite some ether or mine to send transaction.
When sending transaction, your local node would valid transaction, you can learn more by reading source code. Error declare:

```
// ErrInsufficientFunds is returned if the total cost of executing a transaction
// is higher than the balance of the user's account.
ErrInsufficientFunds = errors.New("insufficient funds for gas * price + value")
```

and the valid transaction logic as follows:

```
// validateTx checks whether a transaction is valid according to the consensus
// rules and adheres to some heuristic limits of the local node (price and size).
func (pool *TxPool) validateTx(tx *types.Transaction, local bool) error {
    // Heuristic limit, reject transactions over 32KB to prevent DOS attacks
    if tx.Size() > 32*1024 {
        return ErrOversizedData
    }
    // Transactions can't be negative. This may never happen using RLP decoded
    // transactions but may occur if you create a transaction using the RPC.
    if tx.Value().Sign() < 0 {
        return ErrNegativeValue
    }
    // Ensure the transaction doesn't exceed the current block limit gas.
    if pool.blockChain.GasLimit().Cmp(tx.Gas()) < 0 {
        return ErrGasLimit
    }
    // Make sure the transaction is signed properly
    from, err := types.Sender(pool.signer, tx)
    if err != nil {
        return ErrInvalidSender
    }
    // Drop non-local transactions under our own minimal accepted gas price
    local = local || pool.locals.contains(from) // account may be local even if the transaction arrived from the network
    if !local && pool.gasPrice.Cmp(tx.GasPrice()) > 0 {
        return ErrUnderpriced
    }
    // Ensure the transaction adheres to nonce ordering
    currentState, err := pool.blockChain.State()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if currentState.GetNonce(from) > tx.Nonce() {
        return ErrNonceTooLow
    }
    // Transactor should have enough funds to cover the costs
    // cost == V + GP * GL
    if currentState.GetBalance(from).Cmp(tx.Cost()) < 0 {
        return ErrInsufficientFunds
    }
    intrGas := IntrinsicGas(tx.Data(), tx.To() == nil, pool.homestead)
    if tx.Gas().Cmp(intrGas) < 0 {
        return ErrIntrinsicGas
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: But the balance, as it seen from the console, is much more than what I am trying to transfer. Insufficient funds error is seen even if I try to transfer a single ether. i.e. "abc = {from: eth.accounts[1], to: eth.accounts[2], value: 1}" yields the same error.

Comment: You din't understand `cost == V + GP * GL`. For your situation, V is 1, ethereum gasPrice default is `18000000000`, transaction gasLimit is `21000`, so the `cost = 1 + 18000000000 * 21000', it's far out of your balance.

Comment: Okay. Then what can be the reason behind transfer from eth.accounts[0] to any other account work just fine?

Comment: If you would send transaction, your account must have enough balance, this cost includes transaction_value and  transaction_fee.